# Unexpected compile-time evaluation of recursive constexpr function

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, constexpr

I have a recursive constexpr function that produces unexpected results in Visual Studio 2019.

After program simplification it took the following form:

```
constexpr int f(int * x) {
    int c = 0;
    auto p = &c;
    if ( !x )
        return f( p );
    if ( x == p )
        *x = 1;
    return c;
};

int main() {
    static_assert( f(nullptr) == 0 ); //fails in MSVC
}
```

I would expect that the function call `f(nullptr)` returns `0`, but in MSVC it returns `1`. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/n4Kndon71

The only possibility for it that I see is the execution of `if ( x == p ) *x = 1`. But this means that the pointer on local variable `c` in both caller-`f` and callee-`f` is the same, which shall not be.

Is it a bug in MSVC?

Comment: I agree with your reasoning and think it is a bug in MSVC.

Comment: Replacing `*x = 1` by a non constexpr call([Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qf76dbc1P))  confirms that that branch is taken for msvc. I would also say msvc's bug.

Comment: MSVC bug submitted: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Wrong-compile-time-evaluation-of-recursi/1545857