# Does cross-compilation create exactly the same output as native compilation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, x86-64, cross-compiling

I have a project for Intel/AMD x64 architecture on Visual C++. And I use x86 build tools for cross compilation in the latest Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6. (Actually it was recommended by Microsoft support to workaround the `error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH` and `fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit`  frequently happening with native x64 build tools: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-C3859:-Failed-to-create-virtual-me/10056333)

I expected that native x64 toolchain and x86 toolchain for cross compilation would produce exactly the same assembly code. But in fact it seems that it is not always the case.

The smallest example that I can get is as follows:

```
constexpr float foo(size_t itemCount) {
    return ( 10 - 4.0f * ( itemCount - 1 ) ) / float ( itemCount );
}

int main() {
    constexpr float a = foo(3);
    const float & b = foo(3);
    printf( "%g %g", a, b );
}
```

In Release configuration (`/O2` command-line switch) using native x64 toolchain `<PreferredToolArchitecture>x64</PreferredToolArchitecture>` the program prints `0.666667 0.666667` and the assembly code is

```
00007FF7785E1014  movsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [__real@3fe5555560000000 (07FF7785E2228h)]  
00007FF7785E101C  lea         rcx,[string "%g %g" (07FF7785E2220h)]  
00007FF7785E1023  movaps      xmm2,xmm1  
00007FF7785E1026  movq        r8,xmm1  
00007FF7785E102B  movq        rdx,xmm1  
00007FF7785E1030  call        printf (07FF7785E1040h)
```

And cross-compilation using x86 build tools `<PreferredToolArchitecture>x86</PreferredToolArchitecture>` makes the program printing `0.666667 1` with the assembly code:

```
00007FF689721014  movsd       xmm2,mmword ptr [__real@3ff0000000000000 (07FF689722230h)]  
00007FF68972101C  lea         rcx,[string "%g %g" (07FF689722220h)]  
00007FF689721023  movsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [__real@3fe5555560000000 (07FF689722228h)]  
00007FF68972102B  movq        r8,xmm2  
00007FF689721030  movq        rdx,xmm1  
00007FF689721035  call        printf (07FF689721050h)
```

It is visible that both values were computed during compilation, but they are different now.

To simplify the reproduction, one can just clone [this](https://github.com/Fedr/Cross) GitHub repository.

Is it something expected that the machine code made using cross-compilation can be different or it shall be exactly the same as produced by native build tools?

Comment: The second output, `0.666667 1`, looks like a bug to me. You may want to report it.

Comment: The assembler output by a compiler or cross-compiler depends on lots of interacting design choices, implementation details, and tweakable parameters.   So it's not surprising (even if the result is the same observable runtime behaviour) that different assembler can be produced.   Difference of output like you describe, however, looks more like a bug than (say) an artifact of doing floating point operations in different order.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the result `0.666667 1` in the Visual Studio 17.6.3 `x86`.  Is there any other setting that needs to be changed?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT, build tools must be x86, and compilation target must be x64. Also it is reproducible only in Release configuration `/O2`

Comment: MSVC issue submitted: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/x86-build-tools-create-wrong-x64-code/10394622

Comment: Hi, @Fedor  I noticed that the problem has been fixed. You could close this question by converting the comment to an answer and accepting it. Just a reminder :)

Comment: Hi @MinxinYu-MSFT, thanks for the reminder. As far as I see, the issue is the state "Fixed - Pending Release", so we need to wait for a public release. If you like, please write the answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the report submitted by Fedor:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/x86-build-tools-create-wrong-x64-code/10394622.

> A fix for this issue has been internally implemented and is being
> prepared for release.

Comment: Thanks. There is one more [MSVC bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69431575/7325599) reported almost two years ago. Is there a way to expedite its fix?